# Draw seamless distribution of tweets

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've collected tweets from twitter now I'm trying to draw the distribution of tweets geographically. To do that, I divide the entire square area into small square and count number of tweets in each square. Finally, I use matplotlib to draw the following figure:

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.3, cmap='Accent')
```

[image]

The problem is that the elevation map is not smooth. I'd like a way to draw smooth curve from the data. One example for that in 2D is when we have a histogram of image, we can draw smooth curve over the distribution as follows:
[image]

So my question is that is there a way to draw a smooth surface from the discrete data?

Comment: Just a thought: `repeat()` your data over both dimensions and run [some kind of blur](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter) over it.

Comment: I think there must be a method like in the 2D to infer or polynomialy fit X and Y. Or my approach to draw the height map of tweets count is wrong?

Comment: Well, in your second picture the curve is not a fit. But if you want an actual fit, [surely you can do it](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my answer, here's what you can get with resampling and smoothing ([`gaussian_filter()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter))/spline interpolation ([`RectBivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline)). Note that it would be nice of you to provide a template code that plots your graph, but since you haven't, I had to improvise.

```
import numpy

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def plot(name, method):
    numpy.random.seed(123)

    x = numpy.linspace(0, 50, 51)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, x)
    Z = numpy.zeros((x.size, x.size))

    for n in range(50):
        i = numpy.random.randint(0, x.size)
        j = numpy.random.randint(0, x.size)
        Z[i, j] = numpy.abs(numpy.random.normal()) * 1000

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    if method == 0:
    # regular plot
        ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.3, cmap='Accent')

    else:
        # create a finer grid
        resample_coeff = 2
        Z2 = numpy.repeat(Z, resample_coeff, 0).repeat(resample_coeff, 1)
        x2 = numpy.linspace(x[0], x[-1], x.size * resample_coeff)
        X2, Y2 = numpy.meshgrid(x2, x2)

        if method == 1:
        # smoothing
            from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
            Z2 = gaussian_filter(Z2, 1)

        elif method == 2:
        # interpolation
            from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline
            spline = RectBivariateSpline(
                x, x, Z, bbox=[x[0], x[-1], x[0], x[-1]])
            Z2 = spline.ev(X2, Y2)

        ax.plot_surface(X2, Y2, Z2, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.3, cmap='Accent')

    fig.savefig(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot('t0.png', 0)
    plot('t1.png', 1)
    plot('t2.png', 2)
```

Initial graph:
[image: initial graph]

Smoothing:
[image: Smoothing]

Interpolation (notice the negative regions; that's polynomial interpolation for you):
[image: Interpolation]

Comment: Thank for your code, but the final option doesn't work on my machine. The error lies in this row:
`Z2 = spline.ev(X2, Y2)`
And here is the least recent call:
` File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py", line 683, in ev
    zi,ier = dfitpack.bispeu(tx,ty,c,kx,ky,xi,yi)
dfitpack.error: failed in converting 7th argument 'y' of dfitpack.bispeu to C/Fortran array`

Comment: The quoted line above should be replaced by `Z2 = spline(x2, x2)`

Comment: Well, I wouldn't necessarily say "should", because for me it works as it is. But there's definitely something shady going on in the interfacing to the underlying library.